# How to define multiple key bindings more concisely?

Tags: key-bindings, elisp-macros

I'm trying to write a helper macro to conveniently define keybindings in my configuration file.

The idea is to replace the following configuration entry:

```lisp
(use-package org-roam
  :config
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "SPC n g") #'org-roam-graph)
  (define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-c n g") #'org-roam-graph)
  (define-key evil-visual-state-map (kbd "C-c n g") #'org-roam-graph))
```

With that one:

```lisp
(use-package org-roam
  :config
  (define-evil-key "n g" #'org-roam-graph))
```

Here's how I'm trying to write such a macro:

```lisp
(defmacro define-evil-key (k fn)
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd (concat "SPC " k)) fn)
  (define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd (concat "C-c " k)) fn)
  (define-key evil-visual-state-map (kbd (concat "C-c " k)) fn))
```

But when I press the defined keybinding `SPC n g`, I get the following error: `Wrong type argument: commandp, #'org-roam-graph`.

I'm not really sure, what is going wrong. It seems to me, that the macros should be expanded on the sequence of `define-key` calls, but it doesn't work that way.

Could someone please explain how to properly define this macros and how to debug similar errors in the future?

Comment: Maybe you should define a function (using `defun`) rather than a macro?

Comment: What @Lindydancer said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A macro has to return code.  The return value of your macro is whatever the last form evaluated to:

```el
(defmacro define-evil-key (k fn)
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd (concat "SPC " k)) fn)
  (define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd (concat "C-c " k)) fn)
  (define-key evil-visual-state-map (kbd (concat "C-c " k)) fn))

(pp-macroexpand-expression '(define-evil-key "x" #'foo))
=> #'foo
```

Being what the last `define-key` form had evaluated to.

The specific error "Wrong type argument: commandp, #'org-roam-graph." is related to the fact that macro arguments are not evaluated -- this prevents the `define-key` calls from binding the intended command.

You wanted something like this:

```el
(defmacro define-evil-key2 (k fn)
  `(progn
     (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd ,(concat "SPC " k)) ,fn)
     (define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd ,(concat "C-c " k)) ,fn)
     (define-key evil-visual-state-map (kbd ,(concat "C-c " k)) ,fn)))

(pp-macroexpand-expression '(define-evil-key2 "x" #'foo))
=> (progn
     (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "SPC x") #'foo)
     (define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-c x") #'foo)
     (define-key evil-visual-state-map (kbd "C-c x") #'foo))
```

That said, I see no reason to use a macro for this.  I recommend that you make this a function.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I got the point. The latest macro with `progn` works exactly as I wanted, but in my case it will be easier to write a function instead.